# Easiest way to add REST services to a legacy WebForms application

Tags: .net, rest, webforms

I have an old WebForms application with the following setup:

- Using .NET version 4
- Site is not configured for MVC
- Running Visual Studio 2013

The site is quite large and complex as it has been continuously developed for over 7 years.

What is currently the best way to start adding REST services to the application? I want to have minimal impact on the rest of the site. Upgrading the .NET version, installing MVC etc will all potentially break things on the rest of the site, and I would prefer to not have to deal with that possibility if there is an easier alternative.

I have WCF SOAP services running OK, but have had no success in implementing WCF REST services (see [my other question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26051971/wcf-rest-service-on-web-forms-without-routing)).

Comment: Have you looked at [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api)? It can run on [.NET 4.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541283/run-webapi-without-installing-net4-5)

Answer (score 0):

I got this working using WebApi. The trick is to install the old version of WebApi by running the following command in the NuGet Console:

```
Get-Project <MyProjectName> | Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi -Version 4.0.30506
```

WebApi v2 doesn't support .NET 4.

To reduce any potential impact I commented out the extensionless url handlers that are add to web.config by the WebApi NuGet package.